# Iterate over a Sqlalchemy result row using column objects as keys

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to interate over a (SQLAlchemy Core) result row from a query with (multiple) joins and multiple columns with identical names in the result set. A minimal example:

```
query = select([Table_A, Table_B]).select_from(Table_A.outerjoin(Table_B))

query_result = conn.execute(query)

for row in query_result:

    for column_name, column_value in row.items(): # this breaks due to overlapping column names in Table_A and Table_B
        print(column_name, column_value)
```

Since I have multiple columns with identical column names in my query results I cannot use the column names as keys to iterate over. Instead the column objects would provide a good alternative to use as keys:

```
for col, value in row.items(): # notice the col variable should hold a column object instead of only it's name
    print(col.name, value)
```

I know that I can access the result row using the column objects as indexes: `value = row[Table_A.c.id]` so it feels like it would make sense to also be able to iterate over it using the column objects as keys. Does anybody know if this functionality is available (or can be worked around in some way)?

Comment: Maybe something like `for col in chain(Table_A.columns, Table_B.columns):`, though why would `row.items()` "break" even if some labels overlap?

Comment: row.items() throws a ```sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Ambiguous column name``` if there are two identical column names.

Comment: chaining the columns of all tables might be a solution, though i would prefer to be able to loop through the result without knowing which tables have been used in the query (especially because i'm gonna have to use aliased tables later on, where the aliases might vary depending on the context)